# Sums of iterations

Tags: java, for-loop

Hello I'm a beginner in Java and I have a question regarding summing the iterations. The question is: Write a program that computes the following expression to 4 decimal places:
(1/10) + (2/9) + (3/8) + (4/7) + (5/6) + (6/5) + (7/4) + (8/3) + (9/2) + (10/1)

So far I have:

```
public class Expression
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        float x;
        for ( float m=1, n=10; m<11; m++,n--)
        {
            x = (m)/(n);
        }
```

How would I go about summing all the iterations the for loop makes?

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Why is `m` and `n` inside parenthesis?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Expression
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        float x = 0;
        for ( float m=1, n=10; m<11; m++,n--)
        {
            x += (m)/(n);
        }
    System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it ok to compare the float m with 11 ? I think this may cause a float comparison error (since 11 may be represented as 10.999999)

Comment: @Salles - In the general case using `float` for the loop variable like that could be a problem. However, `float` can represent integers (and do integer addition) exactly in the range being used here.

Answer (score 1):

Nice code, i like it so far!

You need a variable like: `sum = sum + x;` or shorter `sum += x;` within the loop. Define it with `float sum = 0;` before the loop.

You can also directly use x and define it with 0, but the compiler will optimise it anyway, so there is no speed gain.

Comment: Is it a good idea to change m < 11 to (Math.abs(m-11) < 0.0001) in order to avoid float point errors?

Comment: @Salles - Not necessary for integers in this range.

Comment: @Salles You are right to point out that floats need special care when used for loop counters, but in this case it is unnecessary to implement what you have suggested since you would need a significant floating point error, and the integer values in this range can be represented exactly by floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The `+=` operator.  `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x + y`.  In your case, you will have `x += (m)/(n)`, resulting in, ultimately:

```
public class Expression {
  public static void main(String[] args) {           
    float x = 0;

    for ( float m=1, n=10; m<11; m++,n--) {
      x += (m)/(n);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to set x to 0

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 x = (m)/(n);
```

to

```
x += (m)/(n);
```

Since `x` is already in scope outside the loop, it is possible to do this, and `x` will persist between iterations. I recommend changing the loop, however:

```
float x=0;
for ( float m=1; m<11; m++)
  {
     x += (m)/(11-m);
  }
```

It may be more straightforward to read in the future.

Comment: You need to set x to 0